# How does $(function(){ }); works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following code:

```
function example(){
executing_code;

$(function(){
executing_code;
});

(function(){
executing_code;
})();

};
```

I know, that the third one is a self-invoking function and I know the meaning of the second too, but the third isn't invoking, when I invoke example()...
Some days earlier it was the other way round and the second didn't worked. I'm confussed.
Now I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: What made you think the second one is self-invoking? The only function you call here is `$`, not the callback. Without knowing what `$` is, we can't say anything about it.

Comment: @FelixKling Probably the opening/closing parens

Comment: The reason is, that I don't invoke this function manually, but the several alerts in this function shows me, that is invoked automatically

Comment: In the question you say it's not invoked, now you seem to say that it is invoked? It's unclear to me know what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
```

is equivalent to

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

[query api here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Meaning it will fire the code inside the `$(function() {` when the page has finished loading

You need to close the `example()` before the `$(function() {` then call it inside.

Comment: thats a very good and simple explanation. But do you also know, why the third function (function(){ })(); isn't invoked? I tested it with several alert("position");

Comment: @Yvonne.J.M: so is this actually a question about jQuey? Then please tag it as such. The third example "works" as in the function gets executed immediately. Of course you cannot put the alert, everywhere, it has to be inside the function body to be syntactically valid.

Comment: it doesn't get invoked because it is inside of the example function. see this http://jsfiddle.net/uy101tcb/

Comment: Not really. I wanted to know the maening of the constellation in the code and why the code in the $(function...);  runs and the code code in the following (function...)(); doesn't.

Comment: But OP calls the `example` function according to the question.

Comment: I hoped the reason for this was the $-sign, but it wasn't

Comment: @Yvonne.J.M: your question reads exactly the other way round. `$` is not a built-in function. Unless you tell us what it refers to, we don't know what it does!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $( document ).ready(function() {
>   // Handler for .ready() called.
> });
> ```
>
> Which is equivalent to calling:
>
> ```
> $(function() {   
>   // Handler for .ready() called. 
> });`
> ```

from https://api.jquery.com/ready/

This Handler is fired, when your page is fully loaded. You need this, when you place a script on top of you html page. The jquery selector don't find an id or a class or a tag when this element isn't loaded yet. So your script in the `$(document).ready(function(){});` will be executed after every html element is loaded.